# Control the size of CView MFC

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, cview

I have a MFC app where I am using more than one CViews. (Single Document) My problem is that when I maximize the size of the existing view and open another cview, the first cview size automatically get minimized.
Is there a way to keep the first window as maximized or is this the normal behavior with multiple views in MFC?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is unclear. Could you please clarify?

You are referring to MFC SDI application and multiple views.

However, while it is possible to have multiple views in SDI app, there is no way user can control minimizing or maximizing views; the code is responsible for managing views size.

How your views are minimized or maximized?

If your application was created as SDI with multi top-level documents, minimizing/maximizing one frame does not affect another.

Comment: Thanks for the reply JohnCz. The views are minimized and maximized according to the client area. eg : When one view is maximized and covers the entire area, and I open another cview. So the first cview's size changes. I realized it is the normal scenario. Thanks.